# Docker: Invalid restart policy unless-stopped

Tags: docker

The docker Docker version is **1.6.2, build 7c8fca2** :

I'm executing this cmd:

```
  docker run --name=anyname --restart unless-stopped ...
```

I got this error :

```
 docker: invalid restart policy unless-stopped. see 'docker run --help'
```

It's the same in this link :

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/start-containers-automatically/#restart-policy-details

Comment: Please include the output of `docker version`

Comment: Also, did you type the command entirely on the command prompt, use an editor to make a script, or copy and paste parts from places like your browser?

Comment: Thank you for your response, i added the docker version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your version of docker was last seen in a museum when the option you're looking for likely didn't exist. You'll need to upgraded it significantly. The current stable ce version is 17.09.x.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 14.04 , just i execute apt-get install docker.io

Comment: That version is old, install directly from docker, not the Ubuntu repo.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce

Comment: I'm having the same problem with latest release 20.10.17...

Comment: @TheNoobHunter66 with that version, it's a different issue from the OP. Please post a new question.